# How to get all permissions defined in Keycloak's client

Tags: keycloak

How can I retrieve all permissions defined in client using keycloak-admin-client library in Java. For example:

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(keyCloakUrl, keyCloakRealm, keyCloakClientId, token);

// I can get all resources like this:        
List<ResourceRepresentation> resources = keycloak.realm(realm).clients().get(keyCloakClientId).authorization().resources().resources();

// I can get all policies like this:
List<PolicyRepresentation> policies = keycloak.realm(realm).clients().get(keyCloakClientId).authorization().policies().policies();

// So I would expect something like this to work for permissions:
List<ResourcePermissionRepresentation> permissions = keycloak.realm(realm).clients().get(keyCloakClientId).authorization().permissions().permissions();
// But there is no such method
```

Comment: You are looking for all permissions for the current user OR all permissions defined in your keycloak configuration?

Comment: All permissions defined in my Keycloak configuration.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It looks like it's in the REST API (/authz/resource-server/permission) but not the Java API